# Is a cycle a path?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$. Consider 3 vertices $a,b,c\in V$.

Is $\{ab, bc, ca\}$ is consider as a path ?

I think it is, but is just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, assuming that $ab$, $bc$, and $ca$ are actually edges in the graph. (You didn't tell us what the graph looks like.)

Comment: ok, thanks ! :-)

Comment: I disagree with the above comment. Many if not most people demand that *all* vertices are distinct, including the first and last. This is not totally universal though,  so it really depends on what definition you are using for "path".

Comment: by most defintions, all vertices must be dinstinct.  This is what wikipedia and, indeed, all of my resources tell me.

Answer (score 4):

A walk in a graph in which no vertex is repeated is the definition for a **path** (Graphs and Digraphs 5th edition; Zhang, Chartrand, Lesniak).  Since the example you have shown has a vertex repeated, it is no longer a path.  A cycle is not a path by itself (while it is a walk, more specifically a **closed walk**).  However, the cycle you've mentioned does contain a path, but only $P_3:abc$.  Not, as you've noted, $P_4: abca$.  In short, every cycle contains a path as a subgraph, yet the cycle itself is not, strictly, considered a path.  Hope this helps.